# I am trying to send a gmail text to someone

Tags: python-3.x, gmail

so I tried to send it gave me this error
here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\23470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\mess.py", line 6, in <module>
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpServer,25)
File "C:\Users\23470\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 258, in __init__
raise SMTPConnectError(code, msg)
smtplib.SMTPConnectError: (451, b'Request action aborted on MFE proxy, SMTP server is not 
available.')
```

Here is my code

```
import smtplib
smtpServer='smtp.yourdomain.com'      
fromAddr='imranalubankudi@gmail.com'         
toAddr='gmmeremnwanne@gmail.com'     
text= "This is a test of sending email from within Python."
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpServer,25)
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpServer,25)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.sendmail(fromAddr, toAddr, text) 
server.quit()
```

Comment: I made a spelling mistake  sorry

Comment: i have corrected spelling

Comment: i really need an answer its my homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing port to 587. Also your `smtpServer` don't looks right for gmail.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
```

You should also need to login to session.

Here's a simple function that sends a simple text mail through gmail.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def send_mail(send_from, send_to, subject, body):
  
  #The mail addresses and password
  sender_pass = 'your_gmail_password'

  #Setup the MIME
  message = MIMEMultipart()
  message['From'] = send_from
  message['To'] = send_to
  message['Subject'] = subject
  message.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

  session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
  session.starttls() 
  session.login(send_from, sender_pass) 
  text = message.as_string()
  session.sendmail(send_from, send_to, text)
  session.quit()
```

Comment: in  message['From'] should I input the email

Comment: does it send the mail

Comment: Yes. `send_from` is an email address that you want to send from and it corresponds with password. `send_to` is target email.

Comment: i dont see it in my inbox i tried to send it to my self and i dont see it

Comment: You should check gmail security settings to allow third party applications sends an email.

Comment: how would i do it help

Comment: i don't know how to do it